# How to properly invalidate the manager?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, security, vulnerability

In `MyContract`, I am providing special rights to the `manager`. But after some time and for some reason, I want to invalidate the `manager`. The following is my approach:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract  MyContract{
    address manager;
    constructor(){
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function invalidate() public {
        require(msg.sender == manager); // Only manager can invalidate itself
        manager = address(0);
    }
}
```

Is the right way of doing this or does this have some loopholes?

[Reference to 0 address behavior](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/72773/64382).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work great!

The `invalidate()` function is public, meaning anyone can call it. If you want to restrict who can call that address, you should add some require statements.

For example, if you want only the manager to be able to invalidate themself, you would write:

```
    function invalidate() public {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        manager = address(0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @shane. It was just for example purposes. But let me update this so that other people don't get confused.